# Using pattern and required attribute of input field html at the same time

Tags: html, css, regex

How can I both validate the pattern of an input field while use required attribute in an html form. I want to make 2 different warning message for each attribute.

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
                    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                            <input name="email" placeholder="Địa chỉ E-Mail" class="form-control"  type="text" required 
                                   pattern=" /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/"
                                   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Vui lòng nhập địa chỉ email')"
                                   oninput="setCustomValidity('')"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And anyone have a working regex to check valid email? I found that regex on the Internet but it does not work correctly

Comment: Why is my email not accepted? `John.Doe@some.domain`?

Comment: @ctwheels because your top domain is over the expected amount of chars: `\.[a-z]{2,4}$/`. Try something reasonable like: .com, .net, etc

Comment: @zer00ne I know... I was showing the OP that my example is not permitted. They should not be using that regex to *validate* emails. This is not the correct way to do so. I believe it's perfectly **reasonable** to have a tld other than *.com*, *.net* etc. My workplace, for example, uses multiple domains including tlds `.finance` among others. Also, it doesn't accept non-english names. `John.Döe@my.domain`

Comment: When validating an email field, why not go with `<input type="email" required />`? (As opposed to `type="text"`) Problem with setting an incorrect email regex pattern solved :o)

Comment: @ctwheels may bad, did not grok what's inferred. BTW it's **`.domains`**

Comment: anyone have an idea about have two different warning text?

Comment: @PeterSchmeichel , agrm has a point, so go that route.

Comment: @PeterSchmeichel In which two cases do you want to display the warning texts? I'm guessing one is wrong input. The other? Blank field?

Comment: I did it but it gave a default warning text. I want to make a two custom warning texts

Comment: @agrm check blank field, and one for invalid email format

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple :o) Unless you really need to go use the [Constraint Validation API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/form-control-infrastructure.html#the-constraint-validation-api), as you are currently doing, I would go with regular [Form Validation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#client-side-form-validation) which has [pretty good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=form%20validation).

Basically when you apply the `required` attribute on `input` elements they will be matched against a few conditions. One is the field cannot be left blank. A second is an optional `pattern`. In your case, you can specify `type="email"` and the browser will match the input for a valid email address. As far as I can read your request, the following should cover your needs:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="email" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The risk of defining a custom pattern using regex is that you might end up testing for a faulty pattern. In your case, testing for `example@example.cancerresearch` would fail even if it's a valid email address.

Comment: using type="email" sometimes does not work correctly

Comment: In what way does it not work correctly? Does it wrongly pass/fail the validation?